# Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal ssh bash

Tags: bash, terminal

okay heres part of my code when I ssh to my servers from my server.txt list.

```
while read server <&3; do   #read server names into the while loop    
serverName=$(uname -n)
 if [[ ! $server =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
    continue
 fi   
 echo server on list = "$server"
 echo server signed on = "$serverName"
 if [ $serverName == $server ] ; then #makes sure a server doesnt try to ssh to itself
    continue
 fi
    echo "Connecting to - $server"
    ssh "$server"  #SSH login
    echo Connected to "$serverName"
    exec < filelist.txt
    while read updatedfile oldfile; do
    #   echo updatedfile = $updatedfile #use for troubleshooting
    #   echo oldfile = $oldfile   #use for troubleshooting
               if [[ ! $updatedfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
                continue # empty line exception
               fi
               if [[ ! $oldfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
                continue # empty line exception
               fi 
            echo Comparing $updatedfile with $oldfile
            if diff "$updatedfile" "$oldfile" >/dev/null ; then
                echo The files compared are the same. No changes were made.
            else
                echo The files compared are different.
                cp -f -v $oldfile /infanass/dev/admin/backup/`uname -n`_${oldfile##*/}_$(date +%F-%T)
                cp -f -v $updatedfile $oldfile 
            fi          
    done
 done 3</infanass/dev/admin/servers.txt
```

I keep on getting this error and the ssh doesn't actually connect and perform the code on the server its suppose to be ssh'd on.

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to assume that when you run `ssh` to connect to a server, the rest of the commands in the file are passed to the remote shell running in `ssh`. They are not; instead they will be processed by the local shell once `ssh` terminates and returns control to it.

To run remote commands through `ssh` there are a couple of things you can do:

- Write the commands you want to execute to a file. Copy the file to the remote server using `scp`, and execute it with `ssh user@remote command`
- Learn a bit of TCL and use [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)
- Write the commands in a heredoc, but be careful with variable substitution: substitution happens in the client, not on the server. For example this will output your local home directory, not the remote:

  ```
  ssh remote <<EOF
  echo $HOME
  EOF
  ```

  To make it print the remote home directory you have to use `echo \$HOME`.

Also, remember that data files such as `filelist.txt` have to be explicitly copied if you want to read them on the remote side.

Comment: I was assuming that all I had to do was ssh to the server.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like everything the guy above just said is so wrong.

Expect?

It's simple:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/bobskey bob@10.10.10.10 << EOF
echo I am creating a file called Apples in the /tmp folder
touch /tmp/apples
exit
EOF
```

Everything in between the 2 "EOF"s will be run in the remote server.

The tags need to be the same. If you decide to replace "EOF" with "WayneGretzky", you must change the 2nd EOF also.

Comment: You misunderstand... Yes the commands run on the remote server, but **variable substitution happens in the client** before the commands are sent to be run on the remote server.

Comment: Gotcha, I did misunderstand you. But you should be able to get away with double quotes then..I wouldn't rely on expect

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that the -i ~/.ssh/bobskey technique is a good way to simplify this program.